# Turn "overriding commands for target" into error

Tags: makefile

GNU make issues warning if there is more than one recipe for a single target. Is this possible to convert the warning to error to have more visible?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up patching GNU make and rebuilding it from sources (GIT tag 4.1):

```
diff --git a/read.c b/read.c
index 6ff4bcc..f227681 100644
--- a/read.c
+++ b/read.c
@@ -2121,7 +2121,7 @@ record_files (struct nameseq *filenames, const char *pattern,
               error (&cmds->fileinfo, l,
                      _("warning: overriding recipe for target '%s'"),
                      f->name);
-              error (&f->cmds->fileinfo, l,
+              fatal (&f->cmds->fileinfo, l,
                      _("warning: ignoring old recipe for target '%s'"),
                      f->name);
             }
```